# I don't know how to play this videos

Tags: video, video-conversion, jpeg, h.264, image-processing

This videos are from an IP camera but I don't know how or where I can play it. I tried with VLC using a demuxer for h.264 but it doesn't work.

[image]

I tried converting the videos to mp4 but it looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

VideoLan should play just about anything.

Seeing how that didn't work, the next thing would be to look at all the metadata on the video file. Install **MediaInfo** and you should be able to get more information about the video file.

The last thing would be to look if the IP Camera has its own software for playing the video files. *(Could be something like the video feed is encrypted for security reasons.)*